# WildFly 18 NameNotFoundException: jboss -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jms, activemq-artemis

I have followed the [Helloworld JMS example](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-jms) from the WildFly quickstarts to write my own Java client. When I am running the Java program I am getting the exception below. Can anyone guide me on how to access to send message to the JMS queue? I am new to JMS and WildFly.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.handleLookup(RemoteServerTransport.java:200)
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport$1.handleMessage(RemoteServerTransport.java:120)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$receiveMessage$2(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:361)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code is below:

```java
package com.test;
    
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class JmsConsumerWithUser {

    // Set up all the default values
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JmsConsumerWithUser.class.getName());
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World!";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
   // private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = " java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
   // private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY ="java:/JmsXA";
   
    private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "java:/jms/queue/test";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "adminuser";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "Thbs123!";
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context namingContext = null;

        try {
            String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
            String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

            // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
            final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            log.info("Attempting to acquire connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\"");
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
            log.info("Found connection factory \"" + connectionFactoryString + "\" in JNDI");

            String destinationString = System.getProperty("destination", DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            log.info("Attempting to acquire destination \"" + destinationString + "\"");
            Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(destinationString);
            log.info("Found destination \"" + destinationString + "\" in JNDI");

            int count = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("message.count", DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT));
            String content = System.getProperty("message.content", DEFAULT_MESSAGE);

            try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(userName, password)) {
                log.info("Sending " + count + " messages with content: " + content);
                // Send the specified number of messages
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    context.createProducer().send(destination, content);
                }

                // Create the JMS consumer
                JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
                // Then receive the same number of messages that were sent
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String text = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);
                    log.info("Received message with content " + text);
                }
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           // log.severe(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (namingContext != null) {
                try {
                    namingContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  //  log.severe(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

My standalone-full.xml is below:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:8.0">
    <server name="default">
        <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">    
        <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="Test" entries="java:/jms/queue/test"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Yes you answer resolved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNDI bindings created in WildFly are not available to remote clients by default. In order to expose JNDI bindings to remote clients they need to be in a special namespace - `java:jboss/exported/`. However, from a remote client's perspective the `java:jboss/exported/` doesn't exist so it simply uses what comes *after* `java:jboss/exported/` in its lookup.

For example, the `connection-factory` "RemoteConnectionFactory" is configured to bound to `java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`:

```xml
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
```

However, a remote client would look it up at `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`, e.g.:

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

You've got this mixed up in your code and configuration. You're looking up the connection factory using `java:jboss/exported/` which is incorrect and your queue configuration isn't using `java:jboss/exported/`. It should be like this:

```xml
<jms-queue name="Test" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
```

Then your code would effectively look like this:

```java
Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup("jms/queue/test");
```

Incidentally if you simply left the code and configuration alone from the original quickstart everything would work.